# how to get webapplication from a site

Tags: development

I have a site object. How do I get the webapplication from the site? I do not have spcontext available. I am using SharePoint 2010. I am trying to do this in a feature event reciever when my feature in enabled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your feature is activated at the SPSite level, you can do the following...

```
SPSite site = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;
SPWebApplication webApp = site.WebApplication;
```

I'm not near VS2010 to verify, but I believe `properties.Feature.Parent` is correct.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite_members.aspx < Devs best friend.

Comment: +1 Way to go James!

Comment: Lol. I'd have dropped the link as well, but I was on my phone.